# delete rows if there are 2 consecutive empty rows

Tags: excel, vba

what i want to do is to delete rows if there are 2 consecutive empty rows and also to have the empty rows between the header and the first set of data row to be deleted as well.This is my original 
[input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q762h.png) and what i want to have is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZnbVX.png). i have tried to find some codes here and there and come up with this code.

```
Sub Testing()
    Dim i As Long , lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Activesheet
    With ws
        With .Range("C:C")
            fr = .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).row
            If fr > 2 Then
                .Rows("2:" & fr - 1).EntireRow.Delete
            End If
        End With
        i = 1
        For i = 1 To lRow
            If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) And IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, 3)) Then
                .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
           End If
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

However, there are still some consecutive empty rows in the middle of the data set. I know that is because i am increasing `i` which will look at the next cell but i am not sure how to solve it. I am new to vba and even newer to SO posting so let me know if there is anything i am doing wrong and thank you for your help.

Comment: When deleting rows, you want to work from the bottom up.

Comment: Oh, do i need to use `for i =lrow to 1 step-1`?

Comment: Yep that's right.

Comment: Just something for you to consider is not deleting one by one but in one go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only thing you need to do is looping backwards. Instead of

```
For i = 1 To lRow
```

do

```
For i = lRow To 1 Step -1
```

This is because looping from the bottom doesn't have any influence on the row counting of the not yet processed rows, but looping top to bottom does.

Also you can skip `i = 1` right before `For` it doesn't have any influence since `For` starts with whatever `i` is specified as lower bound.

I think your code is just an example but just in case note that `lRow` is never set to a value in your code and therefore is `0`.

---

Note that in this line

```
If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) And IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, 3)) Then
```

your `Cells` objects are not referenced to the sheet of the `With` statement because you forgot the `.` in the beginning. It should be

```
If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 3)) And IsEmpty(.Cells(i + 1, 3)) Then
```

---

Furthermore I **highly recommend** that if you use the [Range.Find method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find)

```
fr = .Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues).row
```

that you **always** specify the `LookAt` parameter as `xlWhole` or `xlPart` (see [XlLookAt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xllookat)). Because the the `LookAt` parameter has no default value (sadly) and if you don't specify it, VBA will use either `xlWhole` or `xlPart` **whatever was used last** by either the user interface or VBA. So you cannot know which one was used before and it will become pretty random (or your code might sometimes work and sometimes not).

---

#### Alternative (much faster) approach …

… is to keep the forward loop and collect all rows to delete in a variable `RowsToDelete` to delete them in the end at once. It is so much faster because every delete action takes time and in this approach you only have one delete action … versus one delete action **per row** in the other approach.

```
Dim RowsToDelete As Range
For i = 1 To lRow 'forward loop is no issue here because we just collect
    If IsEmpty(.Cells(i, 3)) And IsEmpty(.Cells(i + 1, 3)) Then
        If RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then 'first row
            Set RowsToDelete = .Rows(i).EntireRow
        Else 'append more rows with union
            Set RowsToDelete = Application.Union(RowsToDelete, .Rows(i).EntireRow)
        End If
   End If
Next i

'delete all collected rows (after the loop, so delete doesn't affect row counting of the loop)
If Not RowsToDelete Is Nothing Then
    RowsToDelete.Delete
End If
```

Comment: Oh wow, this is really a better approach, i learned a lot from this thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to decrease `i` after deleting a row.

```
For i = 1 To lRow
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3)) And IsEmpty(Cells(i + 1, 3)) Then
       .Rows(i).EntireRow.Delete
       i = i - 1
       lRow = lRow - 1
    End If
   If i > lRow Then Exit For
Next i
```

Comment: Hi, i have tried this while experimenting around and this will make the program loop forever as when you delete the entire row, my actual last Row will decrease but the `lRow` will still be the same. This will make the program loop forever as `i` will never reach `lRow` when i keep decreasing `i` .

Comment: Never mess with `i` manually if it is handled by the `For` loop. This is a very bad approach. Instead use `Step -1` eg `For i = lRow To 1 Step -1` to loop backwards. So the miscounting (because of deleting rows) doesn't happen. • You can do what you did in a `Do` loop where `i` isn't handled by the loop, but don't do it in a `For` loop.

Comment: Sorry, I just available again. You can add If i > lRow Then Exit For.

Comment: hmm this could work after all, glad to know this can work and i will mark it as the answer since it does work but as Peh has mentioned, this is a bad approach.

Comment: @adhywijaya Please note that you now completely messed up the purpose of a `For` loop. This is a **very bad approach**. Either change it into a `Do` loop or use `For i = lRow To 1 Step -1`. Don't use this code it is more working by accident than by purpose.

Comment: @PEH, I am sorry that I only want to give Henry additional code to improve his code. However, yes you're correct. I always use For i = lRow To 1 Step -1 when I need to delete rows by criteria.

Answer (score -1):

```
Dim blankCtr As Integer
blankCtr = 0

With ActiveSheet
For i = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
  If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Rows(i)) = 0 Then
   blankCtr = blankCtr + 1
  If .Rows(i).Cells(1).End(xlUp).Row = 1 Then
  .Rows(i & ":" & .Rows(i).Cells(1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row).Delete
  Exit Sub
 End If

If blankCtr > 1 Then
.Rows(i).Delete
blankCtr = blankCtr - 1
End If

Else
blankCtr = 0
GoTo here

End If

here:
Next i
End With
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow, and thank you for your answer. Rather than just posting a block of code, can you give a short explanation to what the issue is you solved and how you solved it? This will help people who find this question in the future to better understand the issue and how to deal with it.